# Unable to write to a file in Java

Tags: java, unix, file-io, ubuntu-14.04

I have been attempting to create a class that will go through a file and create a HashMap based on the values it finds and that can also write a HashMap to the same file with changed values incorporated with new and already existing ones. The reading of the file into a HashMap is working, however, when I attempt to write said HashMap back to the file with different values and keys, the file does not change what so ever.
Just for clarification, I am on a UNIX-Style system: Ubuntu 14.10

```
public class FConfig {
  public FConfig( String pathToFile ) throws IOException {
    config = new File( pathToFile );
    if( !config.exists() ) {
      config.createNewFile();
    }
  }
  public FConfig( File file ) throws IOException {
    if( !file.isFile() ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    config = new File( file.getAbsolutePath() );
    if( !config.exists() ) {
      config.createNewFile();
    }
  }
  private final File config;
  private BufferedReader fileIn;
  private BufferedWriter fileOut;

  public HashMap<String, String> loadAllProperties() throws IOException {
    fileIn = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( config ) );
    config.setReadable( true );
    HashMap<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
    String line;
    while( ( line = fileIn.readLine() ) != null ) {
      if( line.contains( "=" ) ) {
        props.put( line.split( "=" )[ 0 ], line.split( "=" )[ 1 ] );
      }
    }
    return props;
  }
  public void writeAllProperties( HashMap<String, String> newProps ) throws IOException {
    fileOut = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( config ) );
    HashMap<String, String> props = loadAllProperties();
    props.putAll( newProps );
    config.delete();
    config.createNewFile();
    config.setWritable( true );
    System.out.println( config.canWrite() );
    for( Entry<String, String> entry : props.entrySet() ) {
      System.out.println( entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue() );
      fileOut.write( String.format( "%1$s=%2$s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() ) );
    }
    fileOut.close();
  }
}
```

and I am calling the method

```
FConfig c = new FConfig( new File( System.getProperty( "user.home" ), "fConfig.cfg" ).getAbsolutePath() );

HashMap<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put( "a", "value0" );
props.put( "c", "value1" );
props.put( "b", "value2" );
for( Entry<String, String> e : c.loadAllProperties().entrySet() ) {
  System.out.println( e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue() );
}
try {
  c.writeAllProperties( props );
} catch( Exception e ) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using GEdit I can tell that the file is being modified, but nothing actually changes in the file, I have ensured that the file is writable and readable. I am truly confused as to why this is happening as not even an exception is thrown.

Comment: What are the old values of `a`, `b` and `c` in the file?

Comment: The values of a b and c were non-existent, they were to test adding new properties into the .cfg file

Comment: Does your file contain any newlines? (before or after running the program)

Comment: I separate different properties using newlines, but the file remains unchanged after the attempt to write it

Comment: Move the call to `delete()` before you create the `FileWriter`. Also, have you walked through this with your debugger?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're writing any newlines.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Make this an answer so I can verify it, thanks for the tip

Comment: You don't need all this `exists()`/`createNewFile()` stuff. The file will be created by `new FileWriter()`. Doing it again yourself is just a waste of time, and there is no advantage to be had in creating empty files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the order of your commands. Create the `FileWriter` on your file *after* you create it.

```
public void writeAllProperties( HashMap<String, String> newProps ) throws IOException {
    // fileOut = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( config ) );
    HashMap<String, String> props = loadAllProperties();
    props.putAll( newProps );
    config.delete();
    config.createNewFile();
    config.setWritable( true );
    // You just created a new file.
    fileOut = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( config ) );
```

Also, if you're using Java 7+ I suggest you take advantage of the [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to `close()` (and if you aren't, then you should call `close()` in a `finally` block)

```
public void writeAllProperties(HashMap<String, String> newProps)
        throws IOException {
    // fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(config));
    HashMap<String, String> props = loadAllProperties();
    props.putAll(newProps);
    config.delete();
    config.createNewFile();
    config.setWritable(true);
    try (BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(config))) {
        System.out.println(config.canWrite());
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : props.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
            fileOut.write(String.format("%1$s=%2$s", entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally**, your [`FileWriter(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File%29) constructor is guaranteed to create a new file (since you aren't passing in append). As such, you should really be using something like

```
public void writeAllProperties(HashMap<String, String> newProps)
        throws IOException {
    // fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(config));
    HashMap<String, String> props = loadAllProperties();
    props.putAll(newProps);
    if (!config.canWrite()) { // <-- to check if it is writable
        return;
    }
    try (BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(config))) {
        System.out.println(config.canWrite());
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : props.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
            fileOut.write(String.format("%1$s=%2$s", entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `createNewFile()` and `setWritable()` calls should be *deleted,* not just moved around.

Comment: @EJP Those are required incase the file is set to be readonly by default, please read up on UNIX-Style systems before suggesting solutions for one.

Comment: @MatthewJ. His advice is solid, and they are not required. You can certainly make a call [`File.canWrite()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29) and I've edited my answer.